# Issue with connecting to bitbucket server via ssh on widnows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, bitbucket, permission-denied

I have run command **ssh -p [port] -v git@[host]** and I get:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to stash ([[ip]]:[port]).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
shell request failed on channel 0
```

When I run **git clone --recurse-submodules ssh://git@[host]:[port]/[repo].git** I get:

```
git@[host]: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have added public key to my bitbucket server.
I tried to generate different keys several times I have no clue what to do.

Comment: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git ls-remote ssh://git@[host]:[port]/[repo].git` to debug

Comment: thank you key type was bad. but now I have other issue. git does not ask for password when updating submodules

Answer (score 0):

> git does not ask for password when updating submodules

If those submodules are accessible with the same user as the one identified with your SSH keys, Git should not ask for password anyway.

Even if they are using an HTTPS URL, the user credentials might already be cached locally by a credential helper (`git config --global credential.helper` to check its value).